# push() method not working properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array-push

I'm trying to write a quite simple program that divides an array in another array of defined size smaller arrays, however the `push()` method is not working. Could someone please help me with it?

```
function chunk(array, size) {
  var newArray = [];
  var tempArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length / size; i++) {
    for (let j = size * i, k = 0; j < size * i + size; j++, k++)
      tempArray[k] = array[j];

    newArray.push(tempArray);
  }

  return newArray;
}

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(chunk(data, 2));
```

The ideal output should be `[[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]`.
However im getting `[[7,8],[7,8],[7,8],[7,8]]`.

Comment: move `var tempArray = [];` inside of your first for loop. Currently, you're pushing the same array reference each time, and so modifications to it will impact it within your array

Comment: You are creating only one `temparray` in he very beginning and then overwriting its elements and pushing the same array multiple times

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there. Just move the `tempArray` definition inside your first `for`-loop. Otherwise you would be pushing the same array each time.

Working Example:

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
  const newArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length / size; i++) {
    const tempArray = [];
    for (let j = size * i, k = 0; j < size * i + size; j++, k++)
      tempArray[k] = array[j];

    newArray.push(tempArray);
  }

  return newArray;
};

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(chunk(data, 2)); // [[1, 2],[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 4):

@Behemoth's answer is the **correct one for the question**. But if you want, you can take a slightly different approach like this to reach the solution as well.

```js
function chunk(array, size){
    const newArray = [];
    let i,j;
    
    for (i = 0,j = array.length; i < j; i += size) {
      newArray.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    return newArray;
};

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8];

console.log(chunk(data, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different solution than @Behemoth and @Rukshan

```js
function chunk(array, size) {
  var newArray = [];
  var tempArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length / size; i++) {

    for (let j = i; j < i + 1; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        if (array[size * j + k]) {
          tempArray.push(array[size * j + k]);
        }
      }
      newArray.push(tempArray);
      tempArray = [];
    }
  }
  return newArray;
};

var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(chunk(data, 2));
```

The solution would be [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 9 ] ] instead of [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ]]